# Google Hangouts messages latency vs. typing alert

Tags: google-chrome, latency, google-hangouts

Using the Hangouts app, I consistently see that the ellipsis/dots disappear, and hence tell me the other user is done typing, several seconds before I actually see their message. This is not related to the other user stopping before sending, or similar trivial answers.

It seems the information about the other user typing has better performance or lower latency: why? Is this some UDP vs. TCP or p2p vs. server-side thing?

(I currently have Google Hangouts 2015.528.433.1 on Chromium 40.0.2214.91. My friend uses the Android app.)

Answer (score 0):

it is likely the latency on your end, consider data compression (aka most VPNs) but V8 resolver in chrome should help as well (it does cross over to the apps as well)

Comment: Why would the latency on my end apply to only one of the two communications?